# Python/Beautiful Soup: Scrape Specific Information from Website based on User Input

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a simple web scraping program that pulls lists of cafes from a website based on user input. I have been able to figure out how to do it when the suburb is specifically defined, but I am trying to figure out how to make it so the program scrapes other parts of the website for cafe names automatically when a different suburb is entered. How do I do this?

Here is my code so far and thanks all, also as I am new to Python explanations of why things do/don't work is really helpful. Thanks again

```
 #import stuff to open and scrape websites
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#open url
url = "https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-thornbury"
html = urlopen(url)

#create beautiful soup object: soup object allows you to extract interesting information about the website you're scraping such as getting the title of the page as shown below.
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
type(soup)

#grab cafe names
cafe_names = soup.find_all("h2", class_= "venue-title")

#function to search cafes
def cafe_search():
    user_suburb = input("What Suburb?")
    if user_suburb == "Thornbury":
        print(cafe_names)
```

Comment: You can do this in two steps: First index all the cities using the [sitemap](https://www.broadsheet.com.au/sitemap/melbourne/guide) into a list and then if the user requests for any of the venues which is in the list substitute the place url (probably using f-strings..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a second 'getCafes' function to grab the cafés dynamicly. Looking at the URL's of the site, this should work. (The common link seems to be `https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-SUBURB`) But as always with webscraping, little has to change in order for things to break.

```
 #import stuff to open and scrape websites
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def getCafes(suburb):
    #open url
    url = f"https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-{suburb}"
    html = urlopen(url)

    #create beautiful soup object: soup object allows you to extract interesting information about the website you're scraping such as getting the title of the page as shown below.
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    type(soup)

    #grab cafe names
    cafe_names = soup.find_all("h2", class_= "venue-title")
    return cafe_names

#function to search cafes
def cafe_search():
    user_suburb = input("What Suburb?")
    if user_suburb == "Thornbury":
        print(getCafes("thornbury"))
    elif user_suburb == "Northcote":
        print(getCafes("northcote"))
    # etc....
```

Also change your parser from `lxml` to `html.parser`, since your parsing HTML Pages.
You could also do the last part differently by directly passing in user inputs like this:

```
def cafe_search():
    user_suburb = input("What Suburb?")
    print(getCafes(user_suburb.lower()))
```

But I wouldn't recommend passing in user arguments directly.

Comment: Thanks so much for this thorough answer. It makes sense to me as well (thank you as I am an idiot at this stuff still). 

One question, would I then have to create “elif” statements for all suburbs in my state? Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: @deadant88 Glad to hear that you like the answer :). I think elif's are the best option here. Since python doesn't have a switch-case statement like some other programming languages. You could also try to implement some type of [dictonairy switcher](https://jaxenter.com/implement-switch-case-statement-python-138315.html) but I personally always use if-elif-else statements for code readability. P.S. Don't forget to mark my answer as correct if it helped you ;).

Comment: Thank you! I certainly will, I haven’t had a chance to implement it yet. I’d also appreciate any other feedback on my code “style” am I making silly mistakes?

Comment: Hi @tjallo so I have tried the code you suggested and I am still running into errors (it is probably my fault). I am returning "name errors" saying things aren't defined so I tried to define the variables outside of the functions first, when I attempt to do the url variable it returns this error: InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters.

Comment: Hi @tjallo, thanks so much for your help. With your assistance and my own investigation I found what was breaking the code (conflicting variable) and fixed it. It now runs as expected. Brilliant help.

Comment: @deadant88 Great to hear!